# Usestate and UseEffect are not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use UseState. I know that to make sure it works instantly we have to use "useEffect". Code below logs the new values, but does not change it when it calls the prop.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      "updated",
      itemId,
      highlight,

    );
  }, [highlight, itemId]);
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Example that illustrates the problem:

```
 const [highlight, setHighLight] = useState("Old Value1"); 
const [itemId, setItemID] = useState("Old Value"); 
setItemID(New Value); 
setHighlight(New Value2);

 ((USEEFFECT LOGS "New Value" and "New Value2"))

 console.log(ItemId) == returns "Old Value"
```

Function where I set the itemId and print it.

```
await setItemID(id);
console.log(itemId);


await printSkillChart(id, peer2);
```

Comment: ` does not change it when it calls the prop` What do you mean? When what calls the prop?

Comment: Example: 

 const [highlight, setHighLight] = useState("Old Value1");
  const [itemId, setItemID] = useState("Old Value");

setItemID(New Value) 
setHighlight(New Value2) 

((USEEFFECT LOGS "New Value" and "New Value2"))

console.log(ItemId) == returns "Old Value"

Comment: where are you console logging item id? Can you edit the question with the full snippet?

Comment: I'm just logging it in the console.

Comment: That's not a full code snippet. I know you are logging it in the console. What matters is WHEN. Show me your entire function component.

Comment: setter is internally called in async way. `useEffect` is called in async way too and it's guaranteed it to be called after all setters been called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)